# How can I count occurencies of each string in a list with position of each of them?

Tags: list, haskell

I need to make something like this:

```
func ["a","bb","c","aa","bb","c"] ⟼
  [("a",[0]), ("bb",[1,4]),("c",[2,5]),("aa",3)]
```

with this function:

```
func :: [String] -> [(String, [Int])]
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
func :: [String] -> [(String, [Int])]
func (xs) = func1 (reverse xs)
  where
    func1 [] = []
    func1 (x:xs)
      | notElem x xs = func1 (xs) ++ [(x, [0])]
      | otherwise = func1 (xs)
```

0 is just  a placeholder, how can I put the indices in that position?

Comment: if you are not restricted to using a list as a result data type I would advise you to switch to `Data.Map` - then the `insertWith` function comes in really handy - esp. combined with a `fold` over the `zip` recommended by @Chad-Gilbert

Answer (score 1):

`zip [0..] xs` will give you a list of tuples where the first item is the zero-based index and the second item is the string at that index.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to use `Data.Map` to solve this. (I'm not sure if there's a better way to handle the `zipWith`.)

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

func :: [String] -> [(String, [Int])]
func xs = Map.toList .                          -- [("a", [0]), ("bb", [1,4]), ...]
           (Map.map reverse) .                   -- fromList [("a", [0]), ("bb", [1,4]), ...]
           (Map.fromListWith (++)) $             -- fromList [("a", [0]), ("bb", [4,1]), ...]
           zipWith (\c i -> (c, [i])) xs [0..]   -- [("a", [0]), ("bb", [1]), ...]
```

This starts with a list of tuples pairing each string to a singleton list of its position in the input, then builds a map where each key is mapped to an accumulated list of positions. The accumulated positions are built up in reverse order, which `Map.map reverse` fixes, then the desired list is extracted from the map.

Here is an optimized version, courtesy of dfeuer.

```
func = map (\(a,b) -> (a, reverse b)) .
       Map.toList .
       Map.fromListWith (++) .
       zipWith (\i c -> (c, [i])) [0..]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the index, your helper function just needs an extra parameter that you pass a `0` to initially and increment at each recursive call. You may have to change when you call `reverse` in order to get the indices in the right order, though!

A second part you'll have to consider is the best way to manage the list of pairs you're creating as output. Lists of pairs like this are sometimes called "association lists" and there is a `lookup` function in the Prelude that you can use to get the value associated with a key in such a structure. You might study that function and write a `update` helper to go with it in order to update the value at an existing key.

There is another general approach to problems, however, which @Chad Gilbert is hinting at in his answer. Instead of using recursion directly, you can often define your solution as a composition of transformation and combining operations over the problem structure. Solutions in this form often combine mapping, filtering, zipping, and folding. I would recommend practicing with both kinds of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but this was what I did to solve the problem

```
zipPos :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
zipPos xs = zip xs [0..]

singleHead :: ([String], [Int]) -> (String, [Int])
singleHead (x,y) = (head x, y)

filterFstTuple :: (String -> String -> Bool) -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
filterFstTuple _ [] = []
filterFstTuple con xss@(x:_) = filter (con (fst x).fst) xss

getPos :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, [Int])]
getPos [] = []
getPos xss = singleHead (unzip (filterFstTuple (==) xss)) : getPos  (filterFstTuple (/=) xss)

main :: IO()
main = print . getPos $ zipPos ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "a"]
```

Comment: This is very unclear, and using `head` is widely discouraged.

Comment: It is already assumed that you have a value in the tuple and that the values joined are the same so why traverse fold the same values if you can just get the head.

Well that's the logic that I used, I don't know how the others would do it.

But explaining the code, I guess I'll edit the post

Comment: There are situations where, for the sake of efficiency, a program keeps track of some redundant information about the size/shape of a structure. In such cases, efficiency may demand that the program trust the redundant information to justify an otherwise partial operation. The example I'm currently thinking of is the implementation of `zipWith` in recent versions of `Data.Sequence`, but I know I've seen others. In your case, however, there is no specific need to rely on `head`.

Comment: Ah yes, I remembered another example: tortoise and hare list splitting. If the hare has not reached the end of the list, you can rely on the tortoise not having done so either.